# jquery when removes added class whole element disapears hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class to an image when I hover, the image has already a class that sets the initial size and the added class has a different size, when I get inside the image it works fine as the image change the size but when I leave, the image disappears, is like if I am removing the original class.

```
$('.skill').hover(
  function(){
    $('img', this).addClass('skillW');
  }, function(){
    $('img' , this).remove('.skillW');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code is removing the Element because you called the wrong function. `.remove()` is used to remove the Element.
`.removeClass()` is used to remove a Class from an Element.

So just replace `.remove()` with `.removeClass()`.

Answer (score 2):

`.remove()` is used for removing elements, you must change it to `.removeClass()`

You can also use `toggleClass` for this purpose, Eg below:

```
$('.skill').hover( function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('skillW');
});
```